Can't hide the field Deployment in a workItem
I use this rest api to hide a field from the layout, however it alway fail with the field "deployment" :
Sample url and json:
https://dev.azure.com/myNewDevOpsOrg/_apis/work/processes/035ff023-2a9c-4f38-b76e-e301dd6fdad6/workItemTypes/processName.Bug/layout/groups/Agile.Bug.Bug.Deployment/Controls/Deployments?api-version=7.1
{
  "visible": false
}

Error i got:
Invoke-RestMethod:  {   "$id": "1",   "innerException": null,   "message": "VS402645: The field Deployments does not exists in work item type TOTO-16.Bug",  
"typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.ProcessWorkItemTypeFieldDoesNotExistException,
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",   "typeKey": "ProcessWorkItemTypeFieldDoesNotExistException",   "errorCode": 0,          
"eventId": 3200 }

Layout of the page
"id": "Section3",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "Agile.Bug.Bug.Deployment",
                            "inherited": true,
                            "label": "Deployment",
                            "isContribution": false,
                            "visible": true,
                            "controls": [
                                {
                                    "id": "Deployments",
                                    "inherited": true,
                                    "label": "",
                                    "controlType": "DeploymentsControl",
                                    "readOnly": false,
                                    "watermark": "",
                                    "metadata": "",
                                    "visible": true,
                                    "isContribution": false
                                }
                            ]
                        },

So i don't understand why it won't work, i give the information (ids) it needed but he still can't find it...

I can reproduce the same error to hide the same field.
You can add "controlType": "DeploymentsControl" in the body, then it will work.

Sample PowerShell script:
# Define your parameters
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Create the authorization header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))

# Define the API URL
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/work/processes/22fxx6eb-8sse-4cc0-b197-b3582xx3c6a/workItemTypes/WadeAgile3.Bug/layout/groups/Agile.Bug.Bug.Deployment/Controls/Deployments?api-version=7.1"

# Define the JSON body for the request
$jsonBody = @"
{
    "visible": false,
    "controlType": "DeploymentsControl"
}
"@

# Make the REST API call
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Output the response
$response



Tested on my side, for other field, eg, custom field, the parameter is not needed.
